# Should we store everything required for Authorization in OAuth token

Tags: azure, oauth, jwt, azure-active-directory

I have some idea about OAuth token and used it in my last project. We used to store roles inside it so that resource server (WebAPI) does not have to request any more data to taken any decision on the authorization. Although authorization was based on permissions (that were mapped against roles). And resource server stored the mapping between role and permission.

In my current project, we are planning to use Azure Active directory. But in this project, we need to store one custom field and this field is the basis of all authorization model (along with roles). Although, in AAD (azure active directory), you can have custom fields but these fields cannot be sent in the form of claims.
So, my resource server will have to request this field for every user, once it receives the token from the client application. It can obviously store this in the cache for further request. But this does not look natural to me.

I believe, all the required for authorization should be part of OAuth token.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: If this field is basically part of the resource then you should store it there. The user is identified, so you can keep (advanced) authorization close to the resource.

Comment: Thanks Ruard for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD doesn't support customizing the claims issued in the token.

However as a workaround, you can add the custom claims by querying Azure AD Graph in you project after the token is verified.

Here is a helpful article about [Extending the Azure AD directory schema with custom properties](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-directoryextensions-web/).

Comment: Not sure if I can edit the signed token as it needs to be passed to another service.

Comment: No, it is not able to edit the signed token. Because this is relative to security. The token was signed from Azure Active Directory, and the resource protected by Azure AD will verify the signature every time.

Answer (score 0):

Not particulary for AAD , But if you want to keep everything in token then for sure You MUST encrypt the token. Considering that you are encrypting the token, There are three approaches that come to my mind:

1. Simple one, Authz Server encrypts the token with some private password. On arrival of token on Resource Server, it sends the token to Authz Server for validation and contents (Introspection API or OpenID Connect like API)

In next two approaches, Authz Server encrypts the token and RS decrypts the token locally.

2. When you register the Resource Server, Register it with public key of Resource Server (RS has Public and private key pair). Authz Server generates a random password to encrypt the token payload. Random password is ecrypted using the public key of Resource Server and added to JWT token header. Now when token reaches RS, it first decrypts the password using private key it has and then it uses that password (symmetric key encryption) to decrypt the payload. Everytime a new password needs to be generated to make sure that attacker sees new encrypted String everytime.
3. Similar approach as above, Here when Resource Server is registered (RS must be online) with public key of it, Authz Server contacts the RS and does SSL kind of handshake and they both exchange a long term session key which might actually last for 1 year or more (depending on security constrains of Your enterprise). Then when authz server generates the token, it encrypts it with session key and this time it doesn't add the session key to token header. Token goes to RS, RS check if it has a session key, if it has it tries to decrypt the payload using same session key. For error avoidance, RS can store the validity of Session key as well.